# Beginner JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This doesn't work, when I remove "let" from big value (in the 3 times it appears), it works.Why is that?

```
      let x = prompt("Enter number");

      if (x > 5) {
        let y = prompt("Enter another number");
        let z = prompt("Enter another number");

        let big = y;

        if (y > z) {
          let big = y;
        } else if (z > y) {
          let big = z;
        }

        for (let i = 0; big > i; i++) {
          console.log("hello");
        }
      }
```

Comment: Prompt returns strings not numbers

Comment: And let is scoped to a code block

Comment: `let` is block scoped, so if you declare it in the `if` it's only visible there. Same if you declare it in the `else`. You only want *one* declaration - the initial one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you use the keyword `let`, it reinitializes the variable. ideally you would only use `let` the first time you create the variable.